# Node.js Issue adding packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have setup a node project with following structure

```
--Dockerfile
--package.json
--node_modules
--src
  --index.js
```

I have set package.json start script as

```
"start": "node src/index.js",
```

This is my index.js

```
require('babel/register');
require('./server.js');


import express from 'express';

let app  = express();
let PORT = 3001;

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Hello!');
});

let server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
let host = server.address().address;
let port = server.address().port;

console.log('listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

And the error i am getting is

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

Comment: Use npm install packageName --save The current version of node no need to add --save explicitly.

Comment: i have babel and express in package.json. i have a feeling it has something to do with index.js being inside src directory and hence its not able to import babel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install babel-cli

> ```
> npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-latest
> ```

2. Create .babelrc file and Add

> ```
> echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc
> ```

3. in your package.json

> ```
>     "scripts": {"start": "babel-node src/index.js"}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

while installing packages from np use parameter --save

ex: if you installing express

use

```
npm install express --save
```

so your package.json will include newly added packges

insted of import use:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

steps to fix babel register problem this:

1. remove `require('babel/register');` from server.js
2. create another entry file called start.js
3. in start.js,

   `require('babel/register');
    module.exports = require('./server.js');`

The result is that all code inside server.js will be transpiled on the fly by the register. Please make sure you have configured babel correctly with a .babelrc having the content like below

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

Comment: hi, i did that already and babel+express is there in package.json. I have added more code and the exact error to the post.

Comment: remove .js from server.js

Comment: inseted of import express from 'express';

Comment: use var express=require('express');

Comment: now error changed to Error: Cannot find module 'babel/register'

Answer (score 0):

You can't use transpilation in the same file you are calling `babel-register` .You should either change the `import` statement in your `index.js` to `const express = require('express')` or add the import statement to another file and require it in `index.js` after `babel-register`.Note that `babel-register` only transpiles code only on the subsequent `require` files and not the code in the same file.For more information refer  https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/